# Merge properties into a ResourceBundle from System.getProperties()

Tags: java, properties, parameters

I'm building a ResourceBundle from a file, this bundle holds < String, String> values.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("SQL.properties");
properties = new PropertyResourceBundle(in);
in.close();
```

I would like to add/**replace** on this bundle some properties that I'm passing from the command line using -Dsome.option.val.NAME1=HiEarth

I don't care dumping the old bundle and creating a new one instead.

Could you please tip?

I think that what I need to do is :

1. Create from the bundle a HashMap< String, String>
2. Replace values.
3. Transform the HashMap into a InputStream.  //This is the complicated part...
4. Build the new bundle from that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does some of what you want (converts the System.properties to a ResourceBundle).  Better error handling is left up to you :-)

```
    
    public static ResourceBundle createBundle()
    {
        final ResourceBundle  bundle;
        final Properties      properties;
        final CharArrayWriter charWriter;
        final PrintWriter     printWriter;
        final CharArrayReader charReader;

        charWriter = new CharArrayWriter();
        printWriter = new PrintWriter(charWriter);

        properties = System.getProperties();
        properties.list(printWriter);

        charReader = new CharArrayReader(charWriter.toCharArray());

        try
        {
            bundle = new PropertyResourceBundle(charReader);

            return (bundle);
        }
        catch(final IOException ex)
        {
            // cannot happen
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        throw new Error();
    }
```

Comment: +1. I'd like to add a note of caution though. `Properties.list()` *truncates* values > 40 characters (See bug report: http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=e527dbe27619a23e918ce485c961?bug_id=5089823). Consider using `Properties.store()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way to do it but it's the best I can think of: implement a subclass of `ResourceBundle` that stores the properties you want to add/replace, then set the parent of that bundle to be the `PropertyResourceBundle` you load from the input stream.

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("SQL.properties");
properties = new PropertyResourceBundle(in);
in.close();
MyCLIResourceBundle b = new MyCLIResourceBundle(properties);
// use b as your bundle
```

where the implementation would be something like

```
public class MyCLIResourceBundle extends ResourceBundle {
    public MyCLIResourceBundle(ResourceBundle parent) {
        super();
        this.setParent(parent);
        // go on and load your chosen properties from System.getProperties() or wherever
    }
}
```